# The nusoap client fails to run

Tags: php, nusoap

as it says in the title, I am trying to make a calculator in which the user enters the numbers and it does the most basic operations. The problem is that the client part does not work when I run it, the screen remains blank, I have checked the routes with the libraries and they are perfectly fine so I don't know where the fault lies, here I attach the code for both the client and the server .

server code:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
    include('lib/nusoap.php');

    $server = 'MiServicio';
    $servicio = new soap_server();

    $servicio->configureWSDL($server, 'urn:servidor');

    $servicio->register("calculadora",
    array("x" => "xsd:int", "y" => "xsd:int"),
    array("return" => "xsd:string")

    );

    function calculadora($x, $y, $operacion){
        if($operacion == "suma")
            return $x+$y;
        else if($operacion == "suma")
            return $x + $y;
        else if($operacion == "resta")
            return $x - $y;
        else if($operacion == "multiplica")
            return $x * $y;
        else if($operacion == "divide")
            return $x / $y;
        return 0;
      
    }

    $servicio->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

?>
```

client code:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
    include('lib/nusoap.php');

    $cliente = new nusoap_client("http://localhost:90/ejercicio3/servidorcaculadora.php?wsdl", true);

    $resultado = $cliente -> call("calculadora", array("x"=> '3','y' =>4,'operacion'=>'multiplica'));

    echo($resultado)

?>
```

Comment: Nusoap is a very odd choice of library for new code. As far as I know, the last release from its original maintainers was about ten years ago, and since then the bare minimum has been done to keep it running on sorted versions of PHP. Even using SOAP at all is unusual, but if you do, why not use the built in PHP classes instead? https://php.net/soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when looking at the server.php (via browser):
[image]

You see thant `operation` is missing under then Input

You need to change this line:

```
array("x" => "xsd:int", "y" => "xsd:int", "operation" => "xsd:string"),
```

After this change, `operation` is seen:

[image]

In your client you do send the parameter `x` as a string (`"x"=> '3'`),

why not send it as int, like this: `"x"=> 3` ?